# Not able to create a Stripe plan via the API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I have the following service class:

```
class CreatePlan
  def self.call(options={})
  plan = Plan.new(options)

  if !plan.valid?
    return plan
  end

  begin
    Stripe::Plan.create(
      id: options[:stripe_id],
      amount: options[:amount],
      currency: 'usd',
      interval: options[:interval],
      name: options[:name],
    )
  rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    plan.errors[:base] << e.message
    return plan
  end

  plan.save
  return plan
  end
end
```

When I try to execute in the rails console I am getting:

```
irb(main):002:0> CreatePlan.call(stripe_id: 'test_plan', name: 'Test Plan', amount: 500, interval: 'month', description: 'Test Plan', published: false)
Plan Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `plans` WHERE `plans`.`stripe_id` = BINARY 'test_plan' LIMIT 1
=> #<Plan id: nil, stripe_id: "test_plan", name: "Test Plan", description: "Test Plan", amount: 500, interval: "month", published: false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Yet there is no plan whatsoever in the DB table. Also, there is no plan with such stripe_id in Stripe.

==EDIT

I've changed quite a bit the code but I am still getting the same error.

Here is the Service:

```
class CreatePlan
def self.call(options={})
Rails.logger.info "creating the new plan.."
plan = Plan.new(stripe_id: options[:stripe_id], amount: options[:amount], name: options[:name])
Rails.logger.info "done creating the new plan.."

if !plan.valid?
  Rails.logger.info "plan not valid.."
  Rails.logger.info plan.errors.full_messages
  plan.errors.full_messages
  return plan
end

begin
  splan = Stripe::Plan.create(
      id: options[:stripe_id],
      amount: options[:amount],
      currency: options[:currency],
      interval: options[:interval],
      trial_period_days: options[:trial_period_days],
      name: options[:name]
  )
  Rails.logger.info "stripe insert went well.."
  Rails.logger.info splan.created
rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
  Rails.logger.info "stripe insert did not go well.."
  if e.message != "Plan already exists."
    Rails.logger.info e.to_s
    Rails.logger.error e.message
    plan.errors[:base] << e.message
    return plan
  else
    Rails.logger.info "Plan already exists."
    Rails.logger.info e.to_s
    Rails.logger.error e.message
  end
end

plan.save

return plan
end
end
```

I'm executing it via DB seeding like this:

```
CreatePlan.call(stripe_id: 'basic', name: 'Basic', amount: 999, interval: 'month', currency: 'gbp', trial_period_days: 10)
```

And I am getting:

```
localhost:rails-devise nnikolo$ rake db:seed
D, [2015-06-28T23:50:00.269488 #26190] DEBUG -- :  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
I, [2015-06-28T23:50:00.283726 #26190]  INFO -- : creating the new plan..
I, [2015-06-28T23:50:00.290575 #26190]  INFO -- : done creating the new plan..
D, [2015-06-28T23:50:00.299769 #26190] DEBUG -- :   Plan Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `plans` WHERE `plans`.`stripe_id` = BINARY 'basic' LIMIT 1
I, [2015-06-28T23:50:01.791772 #26190]  INFO -- : stripe insert did not go well..
I, [2015-06-28T23:50:01.791854 #26190]  INFO -- : Plan already exists.
I, [2015-06-28T23:50:01.791892 #26190]  INFO -- : (Status 400) Plan already exists.
E, [2015-06-28T23:50:01.791921 #26190] ERROR -- : Plan already exists.
D, [2015-06-28T23:50:01.792618 #26190] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)  BEGIN
D, [2015-06-28T23:50:01.794350 #26190] DEBUG -- :   Plan Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `plans` WHERE `plans`.`stripe_id` = BINARY 'basic' LIMIT 1
D, [2015-06-28T23:50:01.796032 #26190] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `plans` (`stripe_id`, `amount`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('basic', 999, 'Basic', '2015-06-28 22:50:01.794494', '2015-06-28 22:50:01.794494')
D, [2015-06-28T23:50:01.798160 #26190] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  COMMIT
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would recommend that you try stepping through your code using the byebug gem to see where exactly it's failing. I'm guessing it's where it checks if plan is valid? Can you post the code for your plan model?

Comment: Also, where it says in your console: `Plan Exists (0.4ms)` that doesn't mean that it exists, the rails console is just telling you that it's checking to see if something exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now accidentally closed the browser tab containing the Stripe console and re-opened it and - voila - the Plans were there! It seems that the Stripe console does not refresh even if you click the Plans link repeatedly. You need to close the browser tab and re-open it. That's really lame. Anyway, thank you, @Mark, for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that you might be interpreting the output of the console incorrectly as I have done in the past:

```
Plan Exists (0.4ms) SELECT  1 AS one FROM `plans` WHERE `plans`.`stripe_id` = BINARY 'test_plan' LIMIT 1
```

This doesn't mean the plan exists. The rails console is essentially just telling you that it's checking for the existence of a plan. The console doesn't show you the result of that query so whether it exists or not isn't indicated.

I suspect that your plan isn't being saved for some other reason but your code doesn't log any errors to your console, instead it returns a Plan instance which you could check for errors on:

```
irb(main):002:0> plan = CreatePlan.call(stripe_id: 'test_plan', name: 'Test Plan', amount: 500, interval: 'month', description: 'Test Plan', published: false)
irb(main):002:0> plan.errors.full_messages
```

Try that out and see if there's something else preventing the plan from being saved.